# Start/Stop button not working as expected

Tags: javascript, button

I have recently started learning JavaScript, and I'd like to make a button, with a function, which changes the innerHTML on click. On the first click it changes the text, but after that nothing. Any ideas how could I fix that? Here is the code so far:

```js
let Button = document.getElementById("Btn");

Button.onclick = function change() {

  let turnedOn = false;
  if (Boolean(turnedOn) == false) {
    Button.innerHTML = "START";
    turnedOn = true;
  } else {
    Button.innerHTML = "STOP";
    turnedOn = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<Button id="Btn">STOP</button>
```

Comment: When you invoke the onclick function, you're setting `turnedOn` to false every time, and thus the first `if` will always be true. Move the `turnedOn` variable outside the `onclick` function. Also, no reason to coerce `turnedOn` with `Boolean()` as it's already a boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the `turnedOn` flag outside of the click method, otherwise it will always be false on click.

Also you're setting the flag `turnedOn` inside the `if-else` statement in a reversed way.

Note: As you are only changing the text, you can use `textContent`

```js
const button = document.getElementById("btn")
let turnedOn = false

button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (turnedOn) {
    turnedOn = false
    e.currentTarget.textContent = 'Start'
  } else {
    turnedOn = true
    e.currentTarget.textContent = 'Stop'
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="btn">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `turnedOn` variable only exists within the click handler function. So it is set again to the same value on every click. You could make a global variable or :-

Create a little `ToggleButton` object. To encapsulate the logic for toggling the button. It can toggle itself or other elements can toggle it.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button id="toggleButt">Toggle</button>
        <button id="toggleOtherButt">Toggle</button>
    </body>
    <script>

        function ToggleButton(elem) {
            this.elem = elem;
            this.on = false;
            this.render();
            elem.addEventListener("click", () => this.toggle());
        }

        ToggleButton.prototype.toggle = function() {
            this.on = !this.on;
            this.render();            
        }

        ToggleButton.prototype.render = function() {
            this.elem.textContent = (this.on) ? "On" : "Off";
        }

        const but = new ToggleButton(document.getElementById("toggleButt"));

        document.getElementById("toggleOtherButt").addEventListener("click", () => but.toggle());
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: why complicate which is simple?

Comment: Sure I agree its more involved than other answer but as you've already provided that I'm just providing an alternative. Hope the OP may learn how such functionality can become reusable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting the **turnedOn** variable to false at the start of the function.

You can look at the HTML to find what the current state of the button and then decide to turn the button on or off.

```html
<button id="Btn">START</button>


<script>
    let Button = document.getElementById("Btn");

    Button.onclick = function change () {
    if(Button.innerHTML == "START")
    {
        Button.innerHTML = "STOP";
    }
    else
    {
        Button.innerHTML = "START";
    }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript and do'nt jquery

```
<button id="btnTest" onclick="myclick()">Click OFF</button>

    <script>
        function myclick() {
            var btnTest = document.getElementById("btnTest"); 
            if(btnTest.innerHTML == "Click OFF"){
                btnTest.innerHTML = "Click ON";
            } else {
                btnTest.innerHTML = "Click OFF";
            }
        }
    </script>
```